# convert the value of dictionary from list to float

Tags: python

I have a dictionary named "location" like this:

```
{
    'WA': [
        '47.3917',
        '-121.5708'
    ],
    'VA': [
        '37.7680',
        '-78.2057'
    ],
    ...
}
```

I want to convert to a dic that the value is a float, so it looks like:

```
{
    'WA': [
        47.3917,
        -121.5708
    ],
    'VA': [
        37.7680,
        -78.2057
    ],
    ...
}
```

I tried

```
for key in location.keys():
    location[key] = float(location[key][0,1])
print location
```

it gives me an arror that "float() argument must be a string or a number"

how can I fix that?

Comment: Given that these appear to be coordinates, it makes much more sense to store it as an unmutable tuple rather than a list of two items. Consider doing that.

Comment: I am wondering how did you get that error, are those actual Python lists? Because Python list won't allow you to index using tuple.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary In question OP's typo -- written `,` instead of `:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in here:  `float(location[key][0,1])`

```
# float objects are length 1
for key in location.keys():
    location[key] = [float(location[key][0]),float(location[key][1])]
print location
```

Comment: Not really an addition to this answer, but I'd like to +1 because of showing what the problem is. Not just simply pasting a piece of code: 'this works'.

Answer (score 5):

You can use dictionary comprehension to construct a dictionary which has the values converted to floats, like this

```
print {k:map(float, locations[k]) for k in locations}
```

As suggested by [@Grijesh in the comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590035/convert-the-value-of-dictionary-from-list-to-float/22590051#comment34391397_22590051), if you are using Python 3,

```
print({k:list(map(float, locations[k])) for k in locations})
```

Comment: `list(map(float, locations[k]) )` for python3

Comment: Slightly shorter `{k: map(float, v) for k, v in locations.iteritems()}`, or the equivalent in python 3: `{k: list(map(float, v)) for k, v in locations.items()}`

Comment: Althou as [Joost mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590035/convert-the-value-of-dictionary-from-list-to-float#comment34391439_22590035), `tuple` might make more sense here than `list`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension *within* a dictionary comprehension. Since you need both keys and values, use [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to iterate key-value pairs:

```
res = {k: [float(x) for x in v] for k, v in locations.items()}
```

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) works more efficiently with built-ins, so you may wish to use:

```
res = {k: list(map(float, v)) for k, v in locations.items()}
```

Or, since you have coordinates, for tuple values:

```
res = {k: tuple(map(float, v)) for k, v in locations.items()}
```

The problem with your logic `location[key][0,1]` is Python lists do not support vectorised indexing, so you need to be explicit, e.g. the verbose `[float(location[key][0]), float(location[key][1])]`.