# How to change values in list of values in a dictionary inplace

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

How to replace values in list of values inplace?
From float to int.

`some_dict = {"B1": [-1.0, 3.0], "B2": [-2.0, 4.0], "B3": [-3.0, 5.0], "B4": [-5, -6]}`

Result :

`some_dict = {"B1": [-1, 3], "B2": [-2, 4], "B3": [-3, 5], "B4": [-5, -6]}`

Comment: `power_ports = {k: [int(i) for i in v] for k, v in some_dict.items()}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert the value of dictionary from list to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590035/convert-the-value-of-dictionary-from-list-to-float)

Answer (score 0):

I will try:

```
{k: [int(v[0]), int(v[1])] for k, v in some_dict.items()}
```

Comment: You can also do `for k, (v1, v2)` and `[int(v1), int(v2)]`

Comment: @OlvinRoght yes, it sould also work

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is just simply iterate over the dict items, then iterate over the values list:

```
for key, value in some_dict.items():
    for i in range(len(value)):
        value[i] = int(value[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work or you:

```
new_dict = {k: [int(i) for i in v] for k, v in some_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

```
some_dict = {k: [int(vi) for vi in v] for k, v in some_dict.items()}
```

**Test**

test code with:

```
some_dict = {"B1": [-1.0, 3.0], "B2": [-2.0, 4.0], "B3": [-3.0, 5.0], "B4": [-5, -6]}
print('some_dict = {}'.format(some_dict))

some_dict = {k: [int(vi) for vi in v] for k, v in some_dict.items()}
print('some_dict = {}'.format(some_dict))
```

Output:

```
some_dict = {'B1': [-1.0, 3.0], 'B2': [-2.0, 4.0], 'B3': [-3.0, 5.0], 'B4': [-5, -6]}
some_dict = {'B1': [-1, 3], 'B2': [-2, 4], 'B3': [-3, 5], 'B4': [-5, -6]}
```